# For $N\in \mathbb{N}$, do there exist natural numbers $N<n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_k$ such that $\frac{1}{n_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n_k}=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$N$ is a natural number. 
Is there any $k$ and some natural numbers $N<n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_k$ such that $$\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n_k}=1$$?

Comment: I would guess no. Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: this problem came in my mind after solving a number theory problem. there isn't any other context in my hands. @A.P.

Comment: And which problem is that?

Comment: that is this: prove that for every $i<j$ natural numbers, sum of the reciprocals from i to j can not be an integer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may start from:
$$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=1 \tag{1}$$
and use the identity:
$$ \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag{2}$$
to increase the number of terms in the LHS of $(1)$. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction), any fraction $\frac{x}{y}$ has an Egyptian fraction representation in which the maximum denominator is bounded by $O\left(\frac{y\log^2 y}{\log\log y}\right)$ and a representation with at most $O(\sqrt{\log y})$ terms.

---

Another possible approach is the following one: 
$$ \frac{1}{N}\prod_{k=N}^{N^2-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=1,\tag{3}$$
and if we expand the LHS of $(3)$ we get a sum of Egyptian fractions with a denominator $\geq N$.

We just need to remove duplicates: for such a task, we may use $(2)$.

Comment: In the procedure of increasing the number of terms, is it possible to overlap some fractions that appear in representation? for example generating two $\frac{1}{n}$s in the representation. @Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: It is not clear to me how this construction will enforce the constraint $n_i > N$ for a given $N$.

Comment: You can keep applying (2) to eliminate any numbers below $N$ and any duplicates. Showing that this process terminates is a nice exercise.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Very substantial your link of Wikipedia; thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Jack D'Aurizio best me to it with a cleaner solution, but I'll post this anyway. We will use the result that,

> For any rational $q \in \Bbb Q,$ there exists finitely many $n_1 < n_2 < \dots <n_k$ such that,
>   $$ \sum_{i=1}^k \frac1{n_i} = q $$

There are many known algorithms of constructing such an expansion, but in particular there is a simple, greedy one that continuously adds the largest possible unit fraction such that the sum does not exceed $q.$ This is outlined on [this page](http://nrich.maths.org/6541).

Then then let,
$$ q = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n + 1 $$
Which will gives $n_1 < n_2 < \dots < n_k$ s.t.
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n + 1 = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac1{n_i} $$
Which gives the desired result.